# left alignment in a table with m{width}

Tags: tables, align

How can I make left alignment with m{width} in a table:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!t]
        \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        \processtable{A Comparative Description of Different Algorithms\label{table3}}
        {\begin{tabular}{m{2.24cm}<{\centering}m{2.74cm}<{\centering}m{1.74cm}
                    <{\centering}m{1.74cm}<{\centering}m{4.74cm}<{\centering}m{2.74cm}<{\centering}}
                \toprule 
                \textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{6} \\
                \midrule
                \textbf{A} & B & C  & D& E  & A \\
                \midrule
                \textbf{A} & B & C  & D& E  & A \\
                \midrule 
                \textbf{A} & B & C  & D& E  & A \\
                \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}{}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<{\centering}` is a very odd way to specify centering and only works in some cases. `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.24cm}` would be far more reliable. to get left alignment rather than centering use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.24cm}` to get ragged right (left alignment) rather than centering.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, can I make the text left justified?

Comment: @user137684 i do not know what text you mean but you can put `\raggedright` pretty much anywhere

Comment: @ David Carlisle, m{wth} deﬁnes a justiﬁed column with width wth and cells that are vertically centered, what I mean by text: in the MWE presented in the question the cells of the table contains letters A, B, C, D, E, A, I mean if the cells contain long text, I want it to be vertically left justified.

Comment: @user137684 I know what the array package does (I'm one of its authors:-) but I do not understand your comment, left justified means the same thing as raggedright and that is exactly what I show in my answer.